# How to replace code block in a source file using shell script or python or perl

Tags: python, perl, shell, python-2.4

In my source file there are multiple if clause with same check . I want to make one of the conditional block executed all the time by commenting out conditional statement which is based on text defined after if statement.

```
if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then
  EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-Doracle.fusion.appsMode=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
  export EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
fi

if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then
   EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
   export EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
fi
```

replace with

```
if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then
   EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="Doracle.fusion.appsMode=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
   export EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
fi

#if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then
    EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
    export EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
#fi
```

Can you please suggest me how can  I do this using perl/python or shell script?

I tried perl command that doesn't work for me,

```
perl -0pe '/if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then\nEXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"/#if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then\nEXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
```

Python program which works as expected but considered it as work around, feel there can be better solution. I am not good at shell script and perl.

```
file_loc = 'D:/official/workspace/pythontest/test/oops/test.sh'
new_file_loc = 'D:/official/workspace/pythontest/test/oops/test1.sh'


def modify():
    file = open(file_loc)
    file2 = open(new_file_loc, 'w')
    lines = []
    count = -1;
    found = False
    for line in file:
        if str(line).strip() == 'if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then':
            count = 3;
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            if str(line).strip() == 'EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"':
                found = True
            lines.append(line)
            count = count - 1;
        if (count == 0):
            writeIntoFile(file2, lines, found)
            found = False
            count = -1
            lines = []
        elif count < 0:
            lines = []
            file2.write(line)


def writeIntoFile(file, lines, found):
    for line in lines:
        if found == False:
            file.write(line)
        elif str(line).strip() == 'if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then' or str(line).strip() == 'fi':
            file.write('#' + line);
        else:
            file.write(line)


modify()
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using sed and perl command perl -0pe '/if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then\nEXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"/#if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then\nEXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}" but it didn't work

Comment: I have option where I can read entire file in python and write content into new file and replace the content based of next text found . But feel there can better solution to this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you have tried. Reading it in a comment is almost impossible.

Comment: @DaveCross you might want to include the `[edit]` shortcut for new users to help them find how to [edit]. ;)

Comment: I've always assumed that the edit like was pretty clearly labelled :-) But, yes, I'll add it in the future.

Comment: perl -0pe '/if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then\nEXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
/#if [ "${SVR_GRP}" = "obi" ] ; then\nEXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-DUseSunHttpHandler=true ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"

Comment: @Rakeshnair: Given that we've told you not to put your code in a comment, why would you do it again?

Answer (score 0):

> I want comment out condition based on second line text value

I'm afraid this is a very unclear specification. Please try harder to explain what needs to happen to your text.

This Perl code transforms your sample input into your sample output, but given the vagueness of your question it's impossible to know if it's making the right transformations for the right reasons.

It's a Unix filter (it reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ''; # Paragraph mode

my %seen;

while (<>) {
  my $first_line = (split /\n/)[0];
  if ($seen{$first_line}++) {
    s/^if\b/#if/m;
    s/^fi\b/#fi/m;
  }

  print;
}
```